# CloudFlare strange behavior

Tags: digital-ocean, cloudflare

I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWaFAIRWsA4) tutorial in order to setup CloudFlare with Digitalocean.com. However, I encountered the following problem:

Visiting my website from Chrome, I noticed that there is nothing indication that CloudFlare is working for me. There are no `CF-RAY` or `cloudflare nginx` headers on responses. Also the Claire extension showed that the CloudFlare is not active.  However, when I test the website with [WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/), I can see that all the javascript files where served with CloudFlare caching system.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check with `nslookup` on Windows or `dig` on Unix-based systems if your records are pointing do CloudFlare servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How long did you wait to test? DNS changes take time to propagate, it sounds like your DNS server is still using the old server address.

Check by running `ping address.com`, does it resolve to your digital ocean IP or something else?

Comment: Thanks. Completely missed that. Changing to Google DNS servers solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare is usually set-up at a nameserver level (though CloudFlare Partners alongside those on Business/Enterprise plans can choose to set-up via CNAME). Nameservers usually take time to propagate, this can be 24-48 hours (where as A records or CNAME records usually have a much lower TTL).

You can check which nameservers your computer is pointing to on a Mac/Linux box by:

> dig NS

On Windows you can do:

> nslookup -type=NS

This will tell you the nameservers you computer is pointing to, and whether you need to wait longer for them to propagate to CloudFlare.

Long story short, just be patient. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the google dns `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` in your client IPV4 connection properties. It might be that your ISP is caching the site and you are not able to see the instant changes